# Cakephp: find contained associated parent_id only once

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I cant get rid of some "duplicates" in this query:

```
$data = $this->Collection->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Collection.id' => $id),
        'Collection' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Collection.name'
            ),
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Product' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'id'
                ),
                'order' => 'lft ASC',
            ),
            'Product.Detail' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'product_id', // should occur only once
                    'image_1_zoom',
                    'image_1_slide',
                    'image_1_detail',
                    'image_1_thumb',
                ),
        ))));
```

Detail belongsTo Product and Product hasMany Detail.
My problem is, that I dont want to get more than one Detail with the same product_id.
I tried 'group' with no success. DISTINCT is not possible, since the other fields have different content and are no "real" duplicates.

Any ideas greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: you could try `'limit'=>1` in your `Product.Detail` array?

Comment: Oh hello 'limit' parameter! Never saw you, never used you. Guess I didnt do all of my homework, sorry for that. Thank you very much Ross! If you would transform your comment in an answer I could mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `'limit'=>1` in your `Product.Detail` array!